# Figuring out direction of degrees

Tags: objective-c, math, angle, degrees

I'm probably overthinking this, but, say you have the following variables;

- Starting degrees
- Ending degrees
- Incremented degrees (i.e. starting degrees + X)

How can you figure out the direction of the degrees? I.e, 0->359 being clockwise and 359->0 being counterclockwise.

**Here's a couple of examples:**

```
Starting at: 357 degrees
Ending at: 337 degrees
Incremented by: 20
Direction: Counterclockwise

Starting at: 10 degrees
Ending at: 350 degrees
Incremented by: 20
Direction: Counterclockwise

Starting at: 357 degrees
Ending at: 17 degrees
Incremented by: 20
Direction: Clockwise
```

How would you figure out the direction as safely as possible? One quick dirty solution would be to use module, but, what happens if the incremented number is off by 1-2 degrees?

**The ideal solution** would be a way to detect whichever direction is closest to the incremented number. In case that doesn't make sense, here's an example:

```
Starting at: 17 degrees
Ending at: ~347-357 degrees
Incremented by: ~20-30
Direction: Counterclockwise
```

It wouldn't be clockwise because that difference is approximately ~330-340.

Let me know if it doesn't make sense and I'll try my best to reword it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate two variants for CW and CCW

```
E1 = (Start + Increment) %% 360
E2 = (Start + 360 - Increment) %% 360
```

and check what variant gives smaller absolute difference with ending angle.

```
S:0; E:20; 

if I=20
CW: 0+20=20
CCW: 0 + 360-20=340
E is closer to CW result

if I=340
CW: 0+340=340
CCW: 0 + 360 - 340 = 20
E is closer to CCW result
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work for me when starting was: 0 and ending was: 20.

Comment: Why? Example added